# Object to array with multiple index typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

I have an API that return me many object like this

```
{ id : 1243, string: "things", bool: 1, date: "2021-21-11"}
{ id : 4233, string: "somethingselse", bool: 1, date: "2021-21-11"}
```

I can have many datas for the same **ID** as

```
{ id : 1243, string: "other", bool: 0, date: "2021-27-10"}
{ id : 4233, string: "somethings else again", bool: 1, date: "2021-21-11"}
```

So i made a function to group by id my datas to get something like

```
object = {
        1243: [{
            0: {
                string: "things",
                bool: 1,
                date: "2021-21-11"
            },
            1: {
                string: "other",
                bool: 0,
                date: "2021-27-10"
            }
        }]

object2 = {
    4233: [{
        0: {
            string: "somethings else again",
            bool: 1,
            date: "2021-21-11"
        }
    }]
```

but now i want something like this

```
    alldata = [{
        1243: [{
            "2021-21-11": {
                string: "things",
                bool: 1
            },
            "2021-27-10": {
                string: "other",
                bool: 0
            }
        }],
        4233: [{
            "2021-21-11": {
                string: "somethings else again",
                bool: 1,
            }
        }]
    }]
```

i dont know how to do this, i tried to generate arrays, object but nothing great

Comment: Where is the function you tried?

Comment: Both your examples seem to have square or curly brackets that aren't needed. Not sure if that's just the example code or an actual issue with your conversion though. Anyway, you will want something like `if (!alldata[api_obj.id]) alldata[api_obj.id] = [];` to create the array if it doesn't exist, then `alldata[api_obj.id].push(api_obj);` to add the object to it.

Comment: (Also, always show your attempt. Ideally as [mre]. And please don't add irrelevant tags to your question; the first two are fine but neither angular or typescript is relevant here)